# Likelihood test after cox model application

Tags: r, likelihood-ratio

I am following this https://www.coursera.org/learn/survival-analysis-r-public-health/lecture/s4N9p/how-to-run-simple-cox-model-in-r and I've found that the coxph command ( survival package) perform a likelihood ratio test after the application of one and one only cox model:

[image]

Correct me if I am wrong but, as far as I know, likelihood ratio test perform a test comparing the variance of two models, one of which is nested in the second one: the one that has the lowest variance carries more information about the phenomena I'm studying.

So I'm wondering against which model does coxph perform this LL ratio test. Is between these two ?

$$\lambda_i(t)=\lambda_{0 h}(t) \exp \left(\beta_1 x_{1})\right.$$
$$\lambda_i(t)=\lambda_{0 h}(t)$$

Comment: Related CV post: [Understanding coxph output in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83892/understanding-coxph-output-in-r) and links there in.

Comment: Thanks, that material is amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer for the LR $\chi^2$: it compares the model with a model with no regressors.  This would be an intercept-only model in ordinary linear models, but in the Cox model is an "underlying survival curve-only model".  This tests the global null hypothesis that none of the regressors is associated with the outcome.

Comment: So the two models are the equations I've posted right ?

Comment: One posted one model.   `coxph` automatically runs the null model without your requesting it.

Comment: Maybe I've used the wrong words, the two equations I've written at the end of my post :

$$\lambda_i(t)=\lambda_{0 h}(t) \exp \left(\beta_1 x_{1})\right.$$ -> the one with regressor
$$\lambda_i(t)=\lambda_{0 h}(t)$$ -> the intercept-only model.

Am I right ?

Comment: Yes I think so.